# In Html5 can I use form reset button to just reset visible fields

Tags: html

I have a webpage that uses divs() and some javascript to give the appearance of  a tabbed webpage with multiple tabs, each tab has a set of options. There is a submit button to submit the settings (for all tabs) and start the task, and a reset button that resets the settings to what they were originally set to when the page was loaded.

The trouble is the reset button resets everything on the page, i.e all tabs but the user would expect it to just reset values on the tab they are currently on, what is the best way to achieve this ?

**Example:**
If I'm on tab1 with checkboxes 1-9 I set change checkbox1 to true, then I go to tab2 with checkboxes 10-19 , I change the value of some of these checkboxes, realize my mistake and click on reset to go back to the starting value. But this will also reset checkbox 1 which they would not expect since that tab is not visbile when they click on reset, that is the issue

```
<main>
    <div class="tab">
        <button class="tablinks" id="defaultOpen" onclick="openTab(event, &#x27;menu_basic&#x27;)">
            Basic
        </button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, &#x27;menu_match&#x27;)">
            Match
        </button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, &#x27;menu_artwork&#x27;)">
            Artwork
        </button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, &#x27;menu_genres&#x27;)">
            Genres
        </button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, &#x27;menu_format&#x27;)">
            Format
        </button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, &#x27;menu_classical&#x27;)">
            Classical
        </button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, &#x27;menu_filenaming&#x27;)">
            File Naming 
        </button>
        <button class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, &#x27;menu_save&#x27;)">
            Save
        </button>
    </div>
    <form action="/fixsongs.fix" name="Start" id="Start" method="post">
        <div id="menu_basic" class="tabcontent">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input checked="checked" name="preview" id="preview" type="checkbox" title="Preview only, make no actual changes to your files.">
                        <label for="preview" title="Preview only, make no actual changes to your files.">
                            Preview only
                        </label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label title="If song already fully matched to a MusicBrainz release should it be ignored, metadata updated and filename updated with any new metadata using existing match or rematched as if not currently matched." for="actionIfSongAlreadyMatched">
                            For songs already fully matched 
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="actionIfSongAlreadyMatched" id="actionIfSongAlreadyMatched" size="3" class="combo">
                            <option value="0">Ignore</option><option value="1">Update Metadata and Filename only</option><option selected="selected" value="2">Rematch</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label title="Files can be renamed based on their metadata, but realize this can cause files to be renamed and moved to different folders and this could cause problems for other applications.We usually only recommend you rename songs when they have been matched to a release thus ensuring all songs on same release are renamed together. But you can also rename songs that have been matched song only, songs that have not been matched at all but with existing metadata and all songs even if they have no metadata." for="renameFiles">
                            Rename files based on metadata
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="renameFiles" id="renameFiles" size="5" class="combo">
                            <option value="0">No</option><option value="1">Yes if matched to a release</option><option value="2">Yes if matched to a release or song</option><option value="3">Yes if has metadata</option><option selected="selected" value="4">Yes, for all files</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input checked="checked" name="modifyArtwork" id="modifyArtwork" type="checkbox" title="Adds or replaces artwork. See Artwork tab for more options">
                        <label for="modifyArtwork" title="Adds or replaces artwork. See Artwork tab for more options">
                            Update Artwork
                        </label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input checked="checked" name="modifyGenres" id="modifyGenres" type="checkbox" title="Add or replace genre information, see the Genre tab for more options.">
                        <label for="modifyGenres" title="Add or replace genre information, see the Genre tab for more options.">
                            Update Genres
                        </label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input checked="checked" name="modifyAcousticAnalysis" id="modifyAcousticAnalysis" type="checkbox" title="Modify Mood and other acoustic attributes such as BPM by using acoustic analysis, this is only available in SongKongPro">
                        <label for="modifyAcousticAnalysis" title="Modify Mood and other acoustic attributes such as BPM by using acoustic analysis, this is only available in SongKongPro">
                            Update Mood and other acoustic attributes such as BPM (SongKong Pro Only)
                        </label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input checked="checked" name="matchByFolderOnly" id="matchByFolderOnly" type="checkbox" title="Matching will only occur for a grouping (usually a folder) if all files within the grouping can be matched to a single album">
                        <label for="matchByFolderOnly" title="Matching will only occur for a grouping (usually a folder) if all files within the grouping can be matched to a single album">
                            Only allow match if all songs in grouping match to one album
                        </label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input checked="checked" name="matchAllSongsOnReleaseOnly" id="matchAllSongsOnReleaseOnly" type="checkbox" title="Matching will only occur if every song on the album was matched by a file in your music collection">
                        <label for="matchAllSongsOnReleaseOnly" title="Matching will only occur if every song on the album was matched by a file in your music collection">
                            Only allow match if all tracks in album were matched
                        </label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label align="left">
                            Base Folder
                        </label>
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="3">
                        <label align="left">
                            Sub Folder
                        </label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td><input readonly="readonly" type="text" id="basefolder" name="basefolder" value="E:\HiRes\HDtracks"></td><td><input readonly="readonly" type="text" id="subfolder" name="subfolder" value=""></td><td><button type="button" onclick="shift_left();"><img src="style/images/left_grey.png"></button></td><td><button type="button" onclick="shift_right();"><img src="style/images/right_grey.png"></button></td></tr>
            </table>
            <div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">
                <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel">
                <input type="submit" name="start" value="Start">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="menu_match" class="tabcontent">
        .......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with this general purpose javascript function, tested against text input fields, checkoboxes and selects

```
<div id="menu_basic" class="tabcontent">
    <input checked="checked" name="preview" id="preview" type="checkbox" title="Preview only, make no actual changes to your files.">
    ......
    <div>
        <button type="button" name="reset" onclick="resetOptions(&#x27;menu_basic&#x27;);">
            Reset
        </button>
        <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel">
        <input type="submit" name="start" value="Start">
    </div>
</div>

function resetOptions(divName) {
    var inputs = document.getElementById(divName).getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if(inputs[i].type=='checkbox')
        {
            if(inputs[i].defaultChecked)
            {
                inputs[i].checked=true;
        }
        else
        {
            inputs[i].checked=false;
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        inputs[i].value=inputs[i].defaultValue;
    }   
  }

  inputs = document.getElementById(divName).getElementsByTagName('select');
  for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < inputs[i].options.length; j++) {
        var option = inputs[i].options[j];
        option.selected = option.defaultSelected;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, what's the difference if it does or it doesn't? Second, you can easily achieve this without a reset button. Here is some jQuery code I made:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#button").click(function() {
    $("#box1").val("");
    $("#box2").val("");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id = "box1" type = "text">
<input id = "box2" type = "text">
<input id = "box3" type = "text" hidden>
<input id = "button" type = "button" value = "Reset">
```

And here is pure JavaScript if you prefer:

```js
var reset = function() {
  document.getElementById("box1").value = "";
  document.getElementById("box2").value = "";
}
document.getElementById('button').onclick = reset;
```

```html
<input id = "box1" type = "text">
<input id = "box2" type = "text">
<input id = "box3" type = "text" hidden>
<input id = "button" type = "button" value = "Reset">
```

This way (even though I'm not sure why it matters), it only removes the specified input boxes.

Comment: Firstly, I give an example of  the difference,  if I'm on tab1 with checkboxes 1-9 I set change checkbox1 to true, then I go to tab2 with checkboxes 10-19 , I chnage the value of some of these checkboxes, realize my mistake and click on reset to go back to the starting value. But this will also reset checkbox 1 which they woulfd not expect, that is the issue. The reset functionality provided by form sets the value to the 'original value' not 'blank', so how do I get access to the value it was originally loaded with,your method would always make a checkbox  unchecked.

Comment: @PaulTaylor You do so by storing the default values in JS first. Then, instead of resetting it to emtpy with JS, you set it back to the original values.

Comment: @icecub sounds very cumbersome, is there any way to access the default values in the same way form reset button does ?

Comment: @icecub Currently over multiple tabs  all elements are part of one form, they each have own submit and reset buttons but part of same form. Would there be a way for an element to be members of both an overall form used for submit and a tab specific form just for reset so that reset only reset fields within the tab ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor there isn't really that good of a way to do this with no JavaScript/jQuery. If you are adamant about not using those languages, then I would suggest specific forms for each section. However, this probably won't work all that well for you and I would recommend my answer (it will be the same/less code than storing values and then returning after resetting).

Comment: @PaulTaylor It's not possible. At least, not like that. Technically you could make a seperate form for each page. Then use JS to catch each form submit and prevent the default action. Use JS to collect the values from each form and submit them all with JS.

Comment: @CyanCoding I dont mind using Javascript where necessary but your answer doesnt currently work since it just sets values to "" rather than starting value.

Comment: @icecub I was wondering about the html5 form field of input 'Specifies one or more forms the <input> element belongs to', I thought if reset was only attached to a tab form, and each field on that tab was attached to that form and the main form would that not work ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor I haven't worked with that myself so I couldn't tell. Perhaps it's possible but it seems like a messed up design to me. Even if you have multiple forms, you still need to prevent each individual form from being submitted as a standalone form. I guess you'll have to experiment yourself with this.

Comment: @Icecub it seems that actually multiple forms are not supported, okay since i am generating the page from the server it would be easy enough to generate some hidden fields storing the value the page was loaded with. Im wondering if this is best or could I write a javascript function to store the loaded values in memory when page is loaded, it is possible to do that ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor You already know the default values before the page is loaded. Unless you're trying to retrieve the values previously set by the user. Either way you can set them in JS before the page is even loaded.